# Fatal error: Wordpress theme didn´t work after customising

Tags: php, wordpress, themes

I bought a theme and changed all classes from ivan to stge. it was a customisation wish from the customer.

i changed the hole theme but it always comes an error.

http://www.strategen-gestalter.de/stge/

> Fatal error: Class 'Ivan_Layout_Footer_Normal' not found in /var/www/web591/html/stge/inhalt_sg/themes/sg/framework/stge-framework.php on line 244

The stge-framework.php looks like this:

```
    <?php
/**
 * stge Framework Init Files
 *
 * This will start the default configuration used by stge.
 * 
 * (Table of Contents)
 *  * - Contants - declare contants used by our theme.
 *  * - Helpers/Options - include general framework functions and theme options.
 *  * - Plugin Extensions
 *  * - Base Classes - classes made to be extended
 *  * - Modules
 *  * - Main Layouts
 *  * - Layouts
 *  * - Filters and Actions
 *  * - Main Render
 *
 */

/**
 * Define contants used by theme/framework
 */
    define( 'stge_THEME_NAME', '_s' );
    define( 'stge_FW_VERSION', '1.0.0' );
    define( 'stge_FW_THEME_OPTS', 'iv_aries' );
    define( 'stge_FW', get_template_directory() . '/framework' );
    define( 'stge_OPTS', get_template_directory() . '/framework/options' );
    define( 'stge_OPTS_ASSETS', get_template_directory() . '/framework/options/sections/assets' );

/**
 * Include helpers used by our theme/framework
 */

    // Metabox Options
    require_once stge_FW . '/metaboxes/config.php';
    // Redux Framework Core
    /*
    if ( !class_exists( 'ReduxFramework' ) && file_exists( stge_FW . '/options/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php' ) ) {
        require_once stge_FW . '/options/ReduxFramework/ReduxCore/framework.php';
    }
    */

    // ThemeConfigs
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/theme-configs/theme-configs.php';

    // stge Theme Options
    if ( file_exists( stge_FW . '/options/theme_options.php' ) ) {
        require_once stge_FW . '/options/theme_options.php';
    }

    // Helper: options related functions.
    require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/options.php';
    // Helper: post formats functions.
    require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/post-formats.php';
    // Helper: blog navigation, post pagination and custom comments markup.
    require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/template-tags.php';
    // Helper: custom title, nav fallback and few configurations.
    require stge_FW . '/helpers/extras.php';
    // Helper: title wrapper
    require stge_FW . '/helpers/title.php';

/**
 * Plugin Extensions
 */
    // WooCommerce configuration and extension
    if( class_exists('WooCommerce') )
        require get_template_directory() . '/woocommerce/configuration.php';

    if(function_exists('vc_set_as_theme'))
        vc_set_as_theme();

    // Login with AJAX configuration
    require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/plugin_login_with_ajax.php';

    // Ninja Forms configuration
    require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/plugin_ninja_forms.php';

 /**
 * Base classes, Modules, Main Layouts, Layouts
 */

    // Base Classes
    require_once stge_FW . '/base-classes/class-main-layout.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/base-classes/class-module.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/base-classes/class-layout.php';

    // Modules
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-logo.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-menu.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-live-search.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-social-icons.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-custom-text.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-woo-cart.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-login-ajax.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-responsive-menu.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-responsive-menu-select.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-ads.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-wpml-lang.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/modules/class-wpml-currency.php';

    // Main Layouts
    require_once ( stge_FW . '/main-layouts/class-normal.php' );
    require_once ( stge_FW . '/main-layouts/class-aside-left.php' );
    require_once ( stge_FW . '/main-layouts/class-aside-right.php' );

    // Layouts
        // Top Header
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/top_header/class-two-columns.php';

        // Header
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/header/class-simple-right-menu.php';
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/header/class-simple-logo-centered.php';
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/header/class-classic-logo-centered.php';
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/header/class-classic-right-area.php';
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/header/class-only-menu.php';

        // Title Wrapper
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/title_wrapper/class-layout-title-wrapper-normal.php';
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/title_wrapper/class-layout-title-wrapper-large.php';

        // Content
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/content/class-layout-content-normal.php';

        // Footer
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/footer/class-layout-footer-normal.php';

        // Bottom Footer
        require_once stge_FW . '/layouts/bottom_footer/class-layout-bottom-footer-two-columns.php';

/**
 * Framework actions and filters
 */
    // General actions and filters used by framework (custom CSS, custom JS, author profile and others)
    require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/actions_filters.php';
    if( false == function_exists('getPostLikeLink') )
        require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/like_post.php';
    require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/blog_actions_filters.php';

    // Nice fallback when not using MegaMain Menu Plugin
    if( false == class_exists('mmpm_primary_class') ) {
        require_once stge_FW . '/helpers/menu_fallback.php';
    }

// Render the layouts selected by user
add_action( 'wp', 'stge_main_render', 100);
function stge_main_render() {

    /*****
     * Main Layouts
     ****/
        $layout = stge_get_option('main-layout');

        // Set default in case of not loaded options
        if( $layout == null OR $layout == '' )
            $layout = 'stge_Main_Layout_Normal';

        $main_layout = new $layout();

        stge_set_current_caller('main-layout', $layout);

    /*****
     * Top Header Layout
     ****/

        //Check if layout is not disabled
        if( true != stge_get_option('top-header-enable-switch')
            AND 'stge_Main_Layout_Aside_Right' != stge_get_option('main-layout')
            AND 'stge_Main_Layout_Aside_Left' != stge_get_option('main-layout') )  :

            //Get selected layout from theme options
            $top_header = stge_get_option('top-header-layout');

            // Set default in case of not loaded options
            if( $top_header == null OR $top_header == '' )
                $top_header = 'stge_Layout_Top_Header_Two_Columns';

            // Call class that will display the layout
            $topHeaderLayout = new $top_header();

            // Define current caller
            stge_set_current_caller('layout', 'top-header');

        endif; // ends disable check

    /*****
     * Header Layout
     ****/
        //Check if layout is not disabled
        if( true != stge_get_option('header-enable-switch') ) :

            //Get selected layout from theme options
            $header = stge_get_option('header-layout');

            // Set default in case of not loaded options
            if( $header == null OR $header == '' )
                $header = 'stge_Layout_Header_Simple_Right_Menu';

            // Call class that will display the layout
            $headerLayout = new $header();

            // Define current caller
            stge_set_current_caller('layout', 'header');

        endif; // ends disable check

    /*****
     * Title Wrapper Layout
     ****/
        //Check if layout is not disabled
        if( true != stge_get_option('title-wrapper-enable-switch') ) :

            //Get selected layout from theme options
            $title_wrapper = stge_get_option('title-wrapper-layout');

            // Set default in case of not loaded options
            if( $title_wrapper == null OR $title_wrapper == '' )
                $title_wrapper = 'stge_Layout_Title_Wrapper_Normal';

            // Call class that will display the layout
            $titleWrapperLayout = new $title_wrapper();

            // Define current caller
            stge_set_current_caller('layout', 'title-wrapper');

        endif; // ends disable check

    // Content
    $content_wrapper = 'stge_Layout_Content_Normal';
    $contentWrapperLayout = new $content_wrapper();

    /*****
     * Footer Layout
     ****/
        // Footer is always called, check is made directly in template file.

            //Get selected layout from theme options
            $footer = stge_get_option('footer-layout');

            // Set default in case of not loaded options
            if( $footer == null OR $footer == '' )
                $footer = 'stge_Layout_Footer_Normal';

            // Call class that will display the layout
            $footerLayout = new $footer();

            // Define current caller
            stge_set_current_caller('layout', 'footer');

    /*****
     * Bottom Footer Layout
     ****/
        // Footer is always called, check is made directly in template file.

            //Get selected layout from theme options
            $bottom_footer = stge_get_option('bottom-footer-layout');

            // Set default in case of not loaded options
            if( $bottom_footer == null OR $bottom_footer == '' )
                $bottom_footer = 'stge_Layout_Bottom_Footer_Two_Columns';

            // Call class that will display the layout
            $bottomFooterLayout = new $bottom_footer();

            // Define current caller
            stge_set_current_caller('layout', 'bottom-footer');

    // Render Layout
    if( false == is_admin() ) {
        $main_layout->render();
    }
}
```

any idea why this didn´t work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty self-explanatory, you are trying to create an instance of a class that doesn't exist. On line 244 you have the following:

```
$footerLayout = new $footer();
```

And before it:

```
//Get selected layout from theme options
$footer = stge_get_option('footer-layout');

// Set default in case of not loaded options
if( $footer == null OR $footer == '' )
$footer = 'stge_Layout_Footer_Normal';
```

What this does is it sets the `$footer` variable to `stge_Layout_Footer_Normal` **but only if** `stge_get_option('footer-layout')` is empty. Most likely the value of this option is currently `Ivan_Layout_Footer_Normal`.

It is not a good practice to change the parent theme's code, but since you already did it, you can:

- manually change the `footer-layout` option to `stge_Layout_Footer_Normal` by going to `wp-admin/options.php`
- or change the following code:

`$footer = stge_get_option('footer-layout');`

to

`$footer = 'stge_Layout_Footer_Normal';`